# Create Excel files in java(invalid number)

Tags: java, excel

I have a string like "2,345".I want to put it into a excel cell.I successfully did but in my excel file i got "2,345" as a string.So please suggest me how can i get "2,345" as a number value but with the same format as i used above(comma seperated).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma before inserting it into Excel, cast it to a number before inserting, then format the column to show the comma.

[String replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

In Excel the code to format a `Range` with commas is:

```
SomeRange.Style = "Comma"    'or, recorded version
SomeRange.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"

'a simpler version..
SomeRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```